# Is there a grammatical error in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

The monthly rent shall be enhanced up to 10% every year

The monthly rent shall be enhanced by 10% every year

Note : used 'up to' instead of 'by' in above sentence.

Comment: Welcome @user1010399!  Please check out the new Stack Exchange site for English Language Learners. http://ell.stackexchange.com/ (I'd suggest using "increased" instead of "enhanced" in either of those sentences, by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Bill Franke.  Your use of *enhance* is not appropriate.  You have several options:

> A.  The monthly rent will be increased by 10 percent every year (meaning every year the
>        amount of increase will be 10 percent).
>
> B.  The monthly rent will be increased up to 10 percent every year (meaning a given year's increase could be as high as 10 percent, but it may be less than that).
>
> C.  The monthly rent shall be increased up to 10 percent every year (meaning an increase of up to 10 percent is mandated, but the increase may be less than that).
>
> D.  The monthly rent shall be increased by 10 percent every year (meaning a 10 percent increase is mandated every year).

I assume you are talking about the lease of a property?  If so, the use of *shall* is preferable to *will*, as in options C and D.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence upto 10% says that rent may be enhanced anything between 0% to 10% every year where as the second gives the exactness i.e, the rent will be enhanced by 10% not less nor greater than 10%.

Answer (score 2):

There's a semantic error: the word *enhanced* is **wrong, wrong, wrong**.

> *The monthly rent {will / shall [CHOOSE ONE]} {increase / rise / be raised [CHOOSE ONE]} up to 10% each year*

is good American English (but not the only alternative). The choice between "will" and "shall" may be an American/British English choice.

"Up to 10%" can be replaced with "no more than 10%" or "exactly 10%", depending on which is preferred.

Comment: +1 I think *shall* reflects a legal rather than a geographic dialect: *will* predicts, *shall* mandates.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't know. You could be right about that. You know more about these things than I do. I agree about the predict/mandate difference, though.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that the best solution for this statement is:

> Monthly rent may be increased by up to 10% each year.

or

> The monthly rent may be increased by up to 10% each year.

The inclusion of "The" in the beginning gives the sentence an odd tone, though if monthly rent was referred to previously, it may be well-suited.

For a prospective renter, reading "may be increased" implies that there's a chance that rent will not be increased, whereas reading "will be increased" implies that rent will definitely be increased, regardless of the following "up to". This offers a strategic benefit.

And lastly, I feel that "by up to" rather than "up to" flows better. This may be my personal preference.